# Processing Semicolon on Command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have two batch files which is used to run a large C++ build, the first one starts the processes, creating directories and figuring out what to send to the second script. If certain information is presented to the first script, I have a routine that pops up a window and asks for a password. This is passed to the second script by calling the second script like this

```
call script2.bat -pw:myPassword
```

where myPassword is something the user entered. 
now, i have been testing this script and one of my users password contains a semicolon, so we get this

```
call script2.bat -pw:my;Password
```

I found by putting in quotes I can get this into the second script OK

```
call script2.bat -pw:"my;Password"
```

However, the command line parsing breaks when I try to do this

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ( "%1" ) DO SET switch=%%a&value=%%b
```

if I `echo %1` it shows like this

```
-pw:"my;Password"
```

But with echo on when the script runs I see

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ( "-pw:"my Password"" ) DO SET switch=%%a&value=%%b
```

and it parses as `switch=-pw` and `value="my`

What I eventually need is for value to contain my;Password so I can pass it to another program

Any ideas on how to get this to parse correctly

Here  re 2 batch file that issulstrate the problem:

a.bat:

```
echo on

call b.bat -pw:eatme
call b.bat -pw:eat;me
call b.bat -pw:"eat;me"
call "b.bat -pw:\"eat;me\""
```

b.bat:

```
echo on

echo %1

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ( "%1" ) DO SET switch=%%a&SET value=%%b 

echo switch=%switch% 
echo value=%value%
```

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes in either your command line or to surround your password?

Comment: I tried single quotes, as in c> b.bat -pw:'eat;me' - that was worse, it turned into %1=-pw:'eat and %2=me'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a little trick to get around the way the shell is interpreting the value of "%1" in the FOR /F loop: instead of parsing the string, parse the output of the command `ECHO %1`, like this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a IN ( 'ECHO %1' ) DO ECHO Switch: %%a Value: %%b
```

This works if you put the password in quotes on the command line (`call script2.bat -pw="my;password"`), so we'll have to remove the quotes as follows:

```
SET VALUE=%VALUE:~1,-1%
```

So this is the code I came up with:

```
ECHO OFF

ECHO Arguments: %1

FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a IN ( 'ECHO %1' ) DO (
    SET SWITCH=%%a
    SET VALUE=%%b
)

ECHO SWITCH: %SWITCH%

SET VALUE=%VALUE:~1,-1%
ECHO VALUE: %VALUE%
```

...which returns the following results:

> Arugments: -pw:"my;Password"
>   SWITCH: -pw
>   VALUE: my;Password

Comment: Close, I end up with an extra " at the end

H:\My Documents\test>a

H:\My Documents\test>echo on

H:\My Documents\test>call b.bat -pw:"eat;me"

H:\My Documents\test>ECHO OFF
Arguments: -pw:"eat;me"
SWITCH: -pw
VALUE: eat;me"

Comment: Are you sure you have the syntax correct for `SET VALUE=%VALUE:~1,-1%` ? That should remove the first and last characters, whatever they are...

Comment: I don't know what is going on. It always removes only the first character... maybe there are some spaces at the end that are not visible ? I will look into that.

Comment: Yes, it was trailing spaces... Thanks for the Help !

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the ; with a ^.

```
call script2.bat "-pw:my^;Password"
```

Comment: Just what I needed.  Escaping the semicolon with the caret caused cmd to properly handle my input at least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the script around in double quotes...the semicolon is a command separator so that you could type in multiple commands on the one line. The old days of DOS, and with DOSKEY, you could separate out the commands by hitting Ctrl+T, which is now the semicolon in today's command line processor. Do not worry about the quotes as the command processor will still be able to parse it, the reason the double quotes are used is to get around the long filename/path conventions.

```
call "script2.bat -pw:\"my;Password\""
```

Comment: I must not be understanding something, I thought I did put the command in double quotes, -pw:"my;Password" when it get to the FOR statement, hgowever it shows up as "-pm:"my Password"", the semi-colon is gone. It seems to have something to do with the "for" statement, since when in do echo %1 immediately before the "for" it shows up as -pw:"my;Password".

Comment: Putting the quotes around the whole command line (other than the call) results in an error "The filename, directory name, or volume lable syntax is incorrect"

Comment: Here are 2 batch files that issulstrate the problem
a.bat:
echo on

call b.bat -pw:eatme
call b.bat -pw:eat;me
call b.bat -pw:"eat;me"
call "b.bat -pw:\"eat;me\""

b.bat
echo on

echo %1

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ( "%1" ) DO SET switch=%%a&SET value=%%b 

echo switch=%switch% 
echo value=%value%

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ( "%1" ) DO SET switch=%%a&value=%%b
```

use

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ( "%~1" ) DO SET switch="%%~a" & SET value="%%~b"
```

or (preferably, to my way of thinking)

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ( "%~1" ) DO (
    SET switch="%%~a"
    SET value="%%~b"
)
```

Check HELP CALL and HELP FOR to find out about the %~ syntax for quote removal.