# Escaping illegal characters in params

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

I execute an external batch file from Java and pass a special attribute to it. I've found that several characters are passed incorrectly to my batch file. I couldn't find any limitations mentioned in ProcessBuilder class nor method of escaping those chars.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    /*
     * correct processing: almost everything (even #$*%:'\/~?)
     * fatal error:        |<>
     * trimming:           ;=&
     */
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "batch.bat", "a;b;c;d");
    final Process process = builder.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
    }
    System.out.println("Program terminated!");
}
```

My batch file is just

```
echo %1
```

The code above prints only the first character before the semi-colon (a).

I run this on Win7 and JDK 7 64-bit.

Curently I replacing all these characters with rare ones and the reverse replacement is done later in my final script.

Any idea how to pass these characters correctly without any 'translation'?

Comment: if you try to execute `batch a;b;c;d` from the command line, it will output `a` too. So the behaviour is consistent with the windows prompt. You might find this other post interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477554/processing-semicolon-on-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft Support Site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71247/en-us) stated that

> When a semicolon (;) or equal sign (=) is used as a command line argument in a batch file, it is treated as a blank space.

`cmd /?` stated that

```
The special characters that require quotes are:
     <space>
     &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~
```

So just use

```
batch.bat "a;b;c;d"
```

That is

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "batch.bat", "\"a;b;c;d\"");
```

---

Later I spotted the output is

```
"a;b;c;d"
Program terminated!
```

Where the extra `"` may not be what you want. [Use `%~1` to strip it off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/804646/2040040). That is, change your bat file to:

```
echo %~1
```

Comment: echo a;b;c;d would also output "a;b;c;d"

Answer (score 0):

Create your `ProcessBuilder` with the last parameter *quoted* with `""`

```
ProcessBuilder builder =
               new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "batch.bat", "\"a;b;c;d\"");
```

This would take care of all these characters

```
// fatal error:        |<>
// trimming:           ;=&
```